# What is the easiest way to get the current day of the week in Android?

Tags: java, android

What would be the easiest way to get the current day of the week in Android?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

The Java [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class works.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 

switch (day) {
    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
        // Current day is Sunday
        break;
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        // Current day is Monday
        break;
    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        // etc.
        break;
}
```

---

For much better datetime handling consider using the [Java 8 time API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary):

```
String day = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().name()
```

To use this below Android SDK 26 you'll need to enable Java 8 desugaring in build.gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
}
```

More information on Android's Java 8 support: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: This is appliclable across Java, not Android.

The "Calendar" class is from java.util package

Comment: @Navin Israni What do you mean? I can't see any problem in using java.util. Calendar is added in API level 1.

Comment: be careful, Calendar returns MONDAY as 2 whitch does not meet the standard. Java 8 datetime is correct with MONDAY as 1 (ISO)

Answer (score 41):

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = calendar.getTime();
// 3 letter name form of the day
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date.getTime()));
// full name form of the day
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date.getTime()));
```

Result (for today):

```
Sat
Saturday
```

---

UPDATE: **java8**

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DayOfWeek dow = date.getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println("Enum = " + dow);

String dayName = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("FULL = " + dayName);

dayName = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("FULL_STANDALONE = " + dayName);

dayName = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("NARROW = " + dayName);

dayName = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("NARROW_STANDALONE = " + dayName);

dayName = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("SHORT = " + dayName);

dayName = dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("SHORT_STANDALONE = " + dayName);
```

Result (for today):

```
Enum = SATURDAY
FULL = Saturday
FULL_STANDALONE = Saturday
NARROW = S
NARROW_STANDALONE = 6
SHORT = Sat
SHORT_STANDALONE = Sat
```

Answer (score 30):

Java 8 `datetime` `API` made it so much easier :

```
LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().name()
```

Will return you the name of the day as `String`

> Output : THURSDAY

Comment: Nice! but requires API Level 26 in Android

Answer (score 29):

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
```

or

```
new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Just the same as in Java, nothing particular to Android.

Comment: this returns an int

Comment: You can check that from Calender.SUNDAY etc.

Answer (score 15):

```
public String weekdays[] = new      DateFormatSymbols(Locale.ITALIAN).getWeekdays();
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 Date date = new Date();
 c.setTime(date);
 int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
 System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
 System.out.println(weekdays[dayOfWeek]);
```

Answer (score 12):

If you do not want to use Calendar class at all you can use this

```
String weekday_name = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

i.e., result is,

```
"Sunday"
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is my simple approach to get Current day

```
public String getCurrentDay(){

    String daysArray[] = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday"};

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    return daysArray[day];

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but in my case day numbers starts from 1, not from 0. So, my array looks like this: `String[] days = {"?", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};`

Comment: you can get rid of the "?" then like `int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;`

Answer (score 6):

you can use that code for Kotlin which you will use calendar class from java into Kotlin

```
    val day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

    fun dayOfWeek() {
    println("What day is it today?")
    val day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    println( when (day) {
      1 -> "Sunday"
      2 -> "Monday"
      3 -> "Tuesday"
      4 -> "Wednesday"
      5 -> "Thursday"
      6 -> "Friday"
      7 -> "Saturday"
      else -> "Time has stopped"
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using both method you find easy if you wont last seven days
you use (currentdaynumber+7-1)%7,(currentdaynumber+7-2)%7.....upto 6

```
public static String getDayName(int day){
    switch(day){
        case 0:
            return "Sunday";
        case 1:
            return "Monday";
        case 2:
            return "Tuesday";
        case 3:
            return "Wednesday";
        case 4:
            return "Thursday";
        case 5:
            return  "Friday";
        case 6:
            return "Saturday";
    }

    return "Worng Day";
}
public static String getCurrentDay(){
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you ever want to do this not on Android it's helpful to think about which day where as not all devices mark their calendar in local time.

From Java 8 onwards:

```
LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Detroit")).getDayOfWeek()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define the date string in `strings.xml`. You can do like below.
`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` return value from `1 -> 7` <=> `Calendar.SUNDAY -> Calendar.SATURDAY`

**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="title_day_of_week">
    <item>日</item> <!-- sunday -->
    <item>月</item> <!-- monday -->
    <item>火</item>
    <item>水</item>
    <item>木</item>
    <item>金</item>
    <item>土</item> <!-- saturday -->
</string-array>
```

**DateExtension.kt**

```
fun String.getDayOfWeek(context: Context, format: String): String {
    val date = SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault()).parse(this)
    return date?.getDayOfWeek(context) ?: "unknown"
}

fun Date.getDayOfWeek(context: Context): String {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance().apply { time = this@getDayOfWeek }
    return context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.title_day_of_week)[c[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] - 1]
}
```

**Using**

```
// get current day
val currentDay = Date().getDayOfWeek(context)

// get specific day
val dayString = "2021-1-4"
val day = dayString.getDayOfWeek(context, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score -10):

As **DAY_OF_WEEK** in **GregorianCalender** class is a static field you can access it directly
as foolows

> int dayOfWeek = GregorianCalender.DAY_OF_WEEK;

Comment: you can easily use Calendar class for java and Kotlin too