# How to check day in android?

Tags: android, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to get the current day of the week in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574673/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-in-android)

I want to make an app with the question: "Is it al Friday?"
And than you would see "No" or "Yes" if it's Friday.
So my question is: 
How can i check if today it's friday?
I hope you understand me, otherwise just ask me.

Gaauwe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [java.util.Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Quoting the documentation :

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
if (rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY){
   //do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was an simple solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

see this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html
u probably want to create a calendar instance & set it to the current date and get the day of the week(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) & compare with friday(friday = 6 if i remember correctly?,check on this pls)
or use new date()....

Answer (score 0):

Simply this:

```
    private boolean isTodayFriday(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY;
}
```