# CountDown Timer with specific values in android

Tags: android

I need a *countdown timer* that will decrease its value from a specified time. For example 
`05:45:67`. Now from this value when I start the timer it will go on decreasing until reaching the zero state.

Can you provide me with suitable examples of achieving this?

Comment: have a look at here http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/24/simple-countdown-timer-in-android/

Comment: But this demo will decrease a single value. I want to decrease the counter on the basis of hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: It's worth to take a look in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875403/android-countdown-timer-to-date

Answer (score 1):

Hours, minutes and seconds are basicly multiplicities of thousand, 60 thousand and 3600 thousand of milliseconds. You can decrease number of milliseconds, construct Date object and format it in the way you wish. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    String time = DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss", new Date(millisUntilFinished));
    tv.setText(time);
}
```