# How to get localization of day in week

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I couldnt find a symbol for that in [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

How can I get the current day's localized name?

For example: Monday: 1. day of week ; Tuesday: 2.day, wednesday:3.day .....

I want to get Presentation Number "1"  instead of Monday ...

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574673/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-in-android), you don't need `SimpleDateFormat` to get the numeric day of the week - that is provided by Calendar directly via the [DAY_OF_WEEK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) field (which goes from 1 to 7 where 1 is SUNDAY and 7 is SATURDAY):

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
// Day of Week is a number between 1 and 7 where 1 is Sunday.
int dayOfWeekMondayFirst = (dayOfWeek + 5) % 7 + 1;
```

Comment: I want to get number "1" instead of monday for example

Comment: @metemet06 - I've updated my answer to give the numeric day of week, rather than the textual. Note that the default is Sunday as 1, rather than Monday. I've included the translation to Monday=1 as well.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I was just looking in SimpleDateFormat

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

For the number 1-7, meaning Monday-Sunday, for today:

```
LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getValue()
```

For the localized name of the day of the week:

```
LocalDate                          // Represent a date-only, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.now(                              // Get today’s current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )    // Specify time zone.
)                                  // Returns a `LocalDate`.
.getDayOfWeek()                    // Returns one of seven `DayOfWeek` enum objects.
.getDisplayName(                   // Localize the name of the day-of-week.
     TextStyle.FULL ,              // How long or abbreviated should the localized string be.
     Locale.UK                     // Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in localizing.
)                                  // Returns a string.
```

> Monday

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that long ago supplanted the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`.

To get the day-of-week today, we need the date.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

## `DayOfWeek`

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum pre-defines a set of seven objects, one for each day of the week.

Ask the `LocalDate` object for its `DayOfWeek`.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

Ask the `DayOfWeek` object to automatically localize its name. The [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) method translates the name of the day into any human language specified by a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) such as [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) or [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH).

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

> lundi

Or, in US English.

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US );
```

> Monday

To get the number of the day-of-week, where Monday-Sunday is 1-7 per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, ask the `DayOfWeek` enum object for its value.

```
int dowNumber = dow.getValue() ;  // 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.
```

To get the number 1-7 as part of a larger formatting pattern use `e` or `c` as directed in the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).