# Datepicker display day of week in String format android

Tags: android, datepicker, format

I have a Datepicker (not a DatePickerDialog) which allows customer select the day of the week.
The problem is that I need display the day of the week in String format (MON, TUE, WED, THU,...), not as number.
I have been searching but I couldn't find anything.
Does anyone know how I can do it?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple to use:

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN);
String[] dayNames = symbols.getWeekdays();
```

use your number as index to this array.

good night.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand it. How can I use this sentences in order to display the days in string format?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863860/7973469

Use an Array like:

```js
public static final String[] DAYS = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Fri", "Sat"};
```

Then call it as DAYS[dday] :D