# How to find which day of the week it is - Java

Tags: java, date

there has been a few other question which are pretty much the same, but i cant seem to get my bit of code to work. I get the user input which is there birthday dd/mm/yyyy. I'm ignoring leap years by the way. Im trying to determine what day of the week it was when the user was born. I have to determine how many days they were born from a certain date which in this case is Tuesday the 1st of January 1901. That's why ive done `year-1901`

day=`int day;`

used a switch to determine how many days in each month which is represented by `dayMonth`
so July has 31, feb has 28 etc.

year=`int year;`

```
String[] days =
         {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
howManyDays = ((year-1901)*365 + dayMonth + day - 1);       
whatDay = (howManyDays%7);
days[whatDay]
```

It works sometimes, but then sometimes it doesn't.
Any help is appreciated, if any questions feel free to ask. Thanks in advance and hope it makes sense!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574673/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-in-android

Comment: I dont want todays date, i want it to change depending on the users input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date

Comment: If you want to implement a calendar system, you should state which one is appropriate.

Comment: Modern solution uses `java.time.LocalDate` and the `DayOfWeek` enum. Ex: `LocalDate.of( y , m , d ).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( … )`

Answer (score 18):

You can use Java Calendar.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);

int day_of_week = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

This gives you an int which day of week it is, you can just provide an array to map with the "names" of the days.

Comment: Instead of `c.set(2012, 03, 22);` 
Can i go `c.set(year,  month, day)`
or something like that?

Comment: sure :) it was just an example, i edited it to make it clear.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7):

The Code you have used cannot be implemented in any standard date operations because there are many cases like leap year etc.

Try to use **java.util.Calendar** for date operations that needs to know the details like Week Days, Months etc.

For Even More Complex date function Use **[JODA Calendar](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/old-index.html)**. Joda Calendar is fast and have a lot of operations like no of days between two days etc. You can Look into the above link for more details.

For Now you can use this

```
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(year, month, date) ;
     int i=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Here the value of i will be from 1-7 for Sunday to Saturday.

Comment: would the month be -1 of what ever it is? So if i wanted to enter july i would have to put 6? or would i put 7?

Comment: @Dileep The link points to the google and may not work.

Comment: @EthanEdwards Month will be from 0-11, Week is from 1-7 for Sun- Sat

Comment: Dileep @RedSonja when I set calendar.set(2019, 9, 10) ; could you please help me why it returns 5 instead of 3. Sep 10 is Tuesday.