# Get the name of the day by number

Tags: java, formula

this is probably a very unique question because I have searched on Google for a while & could not find a solution. It is also interesting.

What I need bascailly is a number, which you can get the day name by it.

For example our number is 7, we need to go through a formula to find out it's day name, but for 7 it's basic, all you do is just get "saturday" in the switch statement.

Basically it's simple to get the name, you just done:

```
switch (dayNumber) {
    case 1: return "Sunday"; etc...
```

But my question is pretty complicated I think, and I am not sure if logically there is a possible solution for it.

I want to get the index number of the week, by the number.

examples:

- day 7 - Index: 7
- day 16 - Index: 2 (because you count the first 2 weeks 7 + 7 = 14 and then + 2 = 16 so the day is monday.
- day 24 - index: 3

Why do I need this:

Well I had a question recently in a java course, not related to this, but it has something to do with looping through the month days, so I wanted to be creative & even get the name of the specific day, in a quick way using Mathematics functions and formulas.

So example on how I want to get the name:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
    System.out.println(getDayByInteger(i));
}

public static String getDayByInteger(int day) {
        int dayNumber = 0; //TODO Formula..
        switch (dayNumber) {
            case 1:
                return "Sunday";
            case 2:
                return "Monday";
            case 3:
                return "Tuesday";
            case 4:
                return "Wednesday";
            case 5:
                return "Thursday";
            case 6:
                return "Friday";
            case 7:
                return "Saturday";
            default: return "N/A";
        }
    }
```

I don't mind if it only will support the number range 1-31, but my question focuses on if it's possible to make it work with any number, because you can always build a formula to work for a specific numbers range I think.

Is it even possible for any number? Or will it require checking statements?

Comment: It's hard to figure your question but you seem to be looking for the remainder `%` operator.

Comment: It's not really clear what the input number is meant to be. It sounds like you might be able to get away with just `day % 7` (and then index into an array rather than using switch/case) but your requirements aren't clear.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date

Answer (score 3):

You only have to use modulu and edit your cases:

```
    switch (dayNumber%7) {
        case 1:
            return "Sunday";
        case 2:
            return "Monday";
        case 3:
            return "Tuesday";
        case 4:
            return "Wednesday";
        case 5:
            return "Thursday";
        case 6:
            return "Friday";
        case 0:                     //change case 7 to case 0
            return "Saturday";
        default: return "N/A";
    }
```

Comment: When does `dayNumber % 7` give a result of 7?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: better now?

Comment: Wait there is a problem, it will never give result of 7.

Comment: @kai: Yes, although I still wouldn't use a switch statement - just use an array.

Comment: yes, thats better! but i thought user3123545 want to use a switch case.

Answer (score 1):

you can use reminder operator `%` for this

```
public static String getDayByInteger(int day) {
    int dayNumber = (day % 7) + 1; 
    switch (dayNumber) {
        // case 1 to 7
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For being the first person to understand this 'complex' question.

Comment: and +1 for the sarcasm :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
public static String getDayByInteger(int day) {
    int dayNumber = day % 7; //  Formula..
    switch (dayNumber) {
    case 0:
        return "Sunday";
    case 1:
        return "Monday";
    case 2:
        return "Tuesday";
    case 3:
        return "Wednesday";
    case 4:
        return "Thursday";
    case 5:
        return "Friday";
    case 6:
        return "Saturday";
    default:
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are really looking for, if you wish to figure out the day of the week for a specific date, you might check the following: [How to find which day of the week it is - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333099/how-to-find-which-day-of-the-week-it-is-java)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
int yourDayNumber = 9 ;  // 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, … , 8 = Sunday, 9 = Monday, …
int isoNumber = ( ( ( yourDayNumber % 7 ) - 1 ) < 1 ) ? ( 7 + ( ( yourDayNumber % 7 ) - 1 ) ) : ( ( yourDayNumber % 7 ) - 1 );
String output = DayOfWeek.of( isoNumber ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.US )  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH or Locale.TAIWAN etc.
```

## Details

The [Answer by kai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112099/642706) is correct for the math part, using `% 7`. I consolidated that into a single obnoxious line above using a [ternary function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36536265/ternary-operatorsjava) (see expanded code in last section).

For the other part, getting name of day, you can use new features built into Java using java.time classes.

## `DayOfWeek` enum

The [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) provides a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instance for each of the sever days of the week.

The days are numbered according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.of( 1 ); // Monday is # 1.
```

The [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) method translates the name of the day into any human language specified by a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) such as [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) or [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH).

```
String output = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );  // Or Locale.US or Locale.ITALY etc.
```

> lundi

The purpose of such an enum is to use these objects *instead of* integers. Rather than pass around mere integer numbers, pass around objects such as [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#MONDAY). This makes your code more self-documenting, ensures a range of valid values, and provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

## First day of week

If you must count Sunday as first day of week, adjust to get the ISO 8601 value.

By subtracting one from your code number, we get 1-5 for Monday-Friday. That is just what we want for ISO 8601 numbers. But for Saturday we get -1 and for Sunday we get 0. I take advantage of that fact by adding the negative one or zero to seven to get the desired ISO number of 6 for Saturday and 7 for Sunday. There may be a neater way of doing this, but this approach succeeds according to my limited testing.

```
int yourDayNumber = 8;  // 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, … , 8 = Sunday, 9 = Monday, etc.

int modResult = ( yourDayNumber % 7 );
int isoNumber = ( modResult - 1 );
if ( isoNumber < 1 ) {
    isoNumber = ( 7 + isoNumber );
} else { // Else modResult is 1-5
    // No code needed here.
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "yourDayNumber: " + yourDayNumber + " | isoNumber: " + isoNumber + " | DayOfWeek: " + DayOfWeek.of ( isoNumber ) );
```