# Ternary Operators(Java)

Tags: java, ternary-operator, control-structure

I was recently introduced to ternary operators. I managed to make it through a year and a half of CS school without a professor ever mentioning ternary operators. This is my first quarter where my professor is using them regularly. They seem great for shortening code. So, this is a question that will help me understand the bounds of ternary operators and when/how they can be used. Is there a way to shorten the following code block using one long statements using a ternary operator?

```
if(age < 18){
    minors+=1;
} else if(age < 65){
    adults+=1;
}else{
    seniors+=1;
}
```

Comment: My opinion, but I find that code is much more readable when operators are surrounded by spaces, e.g. `minors += 1;`. As always, there are exceptions, e.g. that statement could be `minors++;` and the postfix and prefix operators should not be separated by space from the value they work on.

Comment: I don't like ternary operators. Find them confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You are updating three unique variables, **one** way to use ternaries here is something like

```
minors += (age < 18) ? 1 : 0;
adults += (age >= 18 && age < 65) ? 1 : 0;
seniors += (age >= 65) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as a single statement:

```
int dummy = (age < 18) ? (minors += 1)
          : (age < 65) ? (adults += 1)
          :              (seniors += 1);
```

The value of `dummy` is unused here. It's just a way to turn the expression into a statement.

Note that I wouldn't consider writing the logic like this in practice. There are multiple side-effects in the code, and that makes it hard to understand.

I think the intent of your current code is very clear as written. Ternary expressions have a tendency to make the code harder to read, in my experience.

Comment: The ternary operator can be a great replacement for multiple assignment *statements*. The problem here is not the multiple statements, but the fact that they update three different *variables*.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is not a good fit for your code because you are changing 3 different variables. I would leave your code as it is.

Suppose, on the other hand, that you had this

```
if (age < 18) {
    number += 1;
} else if (age < 65) {
    number = 8;
} else if (age < 90) {
    number += 2;
} else {
    number = 13;
}
```

This could be rewritten to look like a kind of `switch`:

```
number = age < 18 ? number + 1 :
         age < 65 ? 8          :
         age < 90 ? number + 2 :
                    13;
```

I think this is an improvement on the `if` version. However, it is not common to nest ternary operators in this way, so you may confuse people looking at your code if you used this version.