# Android , get ID if the shared calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I try to set event on a calendar that is shared with me. I know that I should use id of the calendar. However I've got problem. Here's my code :

```
@OnClick(R.id.add_event_button)
    public void addEvent() {

        CalendarDB calendar = (CalendarDB) mCalendarSpinner.getSelectedItem();
        Long id = calendar.getId();
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("calendar_id", 1);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/Berlin");  // Here choose your location time zone
        event.put("title", "test application");
        event.put("description",  "This is test event");
        event.put("eventLocation", "School");
        event.put("dtstart", System.currentTimeMillis());
        event.put("dtend", System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800 * 1000);
        event.put("allDay", 0);
        // status: 0~ tentative; 1~ confirmed; 2~ canceled
        // event.put("eventStatus", 1);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID,8);
        Uri l_eventUri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        } else {
            l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
        }
        Uri l_uri = this.getContentResolver()
                .insert(l_eventUri, event);
        Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

That works and event is being added however , the id's of the calendars are unknown - I mean I try to set them manually - 1,2,3 and so on and figure it out on which calendar event will be added. Google API site says that id should be Long , when I get calendar list I'm getting string as id - name of the calendar. The same situation is in android.provider CalendarContract.class :

```
public static final String CALENDAR_ID = "calendar_id";
```

When I set that id as a parameter the app crashes - it needs Long argument. So, how can I get id;s of the shared calendars ? Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 1):

[What is the easiest way to get the current day of the week in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574673/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-in-android)

so you will get the current day and same way you will get current date and in th esame way number of days for same date . just calculate now