# how to change backgrounds color of cardview day wise?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-calendar

I'm working on one app. In that app, there is a card view. I want to change background color of the card view day wise.

Like 
Monday = red color
Tuesday = Green color

till Sunday! and from next Monday, it will then start from first like Monday=red color

Any idea? how to achieve this?

I tried this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());
```

It gives me output like this

```
Sunday, April 19, 2020
```

now, how can I use this to change the background color?

Comment: Please make sure you show us what you have tried

Comment: I even don't know how to implement it as I'm a beginner. I tried to search here but I didn't found any resources. any little idea will help me to achieve that

Comment: Please share us what you have tried, what you explained, is easy to implement with switch case and set numbers to each day, but for more clarification share us your code.

Comment: Can you include an image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ParisaBaastani Please check again, I have updated it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to get the current day of the week in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574673/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format dates and times into a human-readable string, with respect to the user's locale.

Example to get the current day of the week (e.g. "Sunday"):

```
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String dayofweek=sd.format(c.getTime());
```

Now change the background color :

```
if (dayofweek.equals("Saturday")) {
    cardview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color.white));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int dayOfWeek=bday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  // Returns 3, for Tuesday

Then use if ,else if statements for different colours for different days accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the following code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);


switch (dayOfWeek) {
  case Calendar.MONDAY:
    cardView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_monday));
    break;
  case Calendar.TUESDAY:
    cardView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_tuesday));
    break;
  case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
    cardView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_wednesday));
    break;
  case Calendar.THURSDAY:
    cardView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_thursday));
    break;
  case Calendar.FRIDAY:
    cardView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_friday));
    break;
  case Calendar.SATURDAY:
    cardView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_saturday));
    break;
  case Calendar.SUNDAY:
    cardView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_sunday));
    break;
}
```