# Can I set which days the alarm turns on with alarm manager?

Tags: android-studio

Alarm manager can save which days to trigger the alarm, case like in AlarmClock with

```
android.intent.extra.alarm.DAYS

Alarm.set(message, hour, min,daysOfweek[])

//////Alarm CLock Display/////
Walk 8:55 M W F S
```

How do I get alarm manager to do that so it fires on specific days?

Comment: This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574673/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to get the current day of the week in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574673/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-in-android)